# Зачем нужен балансировщик нагрузки перед ingress kubernetes?

Tags: devops, kubernetes

Пытаюсь сделать точку входа через kubernetes ingress.

Для чего создаю сам ресурс:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test_ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nginx.cluster.local
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-test1
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /admin
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-test2
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Также, для него нужен контроллер. Это выглядит логично. Беру официально поддерживаемый [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

Ставлю на кластер между виртуальными машинами, на "голом" железе.
Так что взял соответствующий контроллер:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

**Вопрос:** а для чего нужна балансировка перед ingress, например `haproxy`? Разве `nginx controller` не может балансировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации ingress-nginx описан этот момент https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/

Если в кратце, то внешний балансировщик должен использоваться для того, чтоб создать отказоустойчивую, единую точку входа. Можно обойтись и без внешнего балансировщика, посмотрите в сторону [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/)

Comment: Да, взял `metalib`. Хотя по прежнему осталось непонимание. Почему вне `kubernetes` я могу использовать `nginx upstream` для балансировки, но для `ingress` обязателен балансировщик. Почему не сделать это на уровне конфига `ingress объекта`, что будет подтянут в `nginx controller`. И просто назначить входной точкой контроллер.

Comment: Вообще можно, просто вывести порт nginx наружу, но тогда если нода на которой находится контролер и на которую навешен днс упадет, то все сервисы окажутся недоступными